# Bad Gateway, Drupal, Redmine via VM centos to host windows

Tags: drupal, centos, redmine, host, bad-gateway

I have one VMs CentOS inside I have installed drupal and redmine. I did my redmine.conf and drupal.conf. But when I want to open the browser on my I have Bad Gateway error. And I don't understand.
Here my .conf files: 
redmine:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/flaman-m/.gem/ruby/gems/passenger-5.0.10/buil$
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerRoot /home/flaman-m/.gem/ruby/gems/passenger-5.0.10
        PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin     morgane
        ServerName srvb.quest-etna.nx
        DocumentRoot /opt/redmine/public
        #PassengerEnabled on
        #RailsEnv production
        ErrorLog /mnt/nfs/logs/redmine/error.log
        CustomLog /mnt/nfs/logs/redmine/access.log combined
        <Directory /mnt/nfs/logs/redmine>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here drupal:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      drupal.flaman-m-quest-etna.nx/
        ServerAdmin     morganeflamant@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot    /opt/drupal
        DirectoryIndex  index.php
        ErrorLog        /mnt/nfs/logs/drupal/error.log
        CustomLog       /mnt/nfs/logs/drupal/access.log combined
        LogLevel        warn
        <Directory /mnt/nfs/logs/drupal>
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here my hosts windows :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
# 102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com # source server
# 38.25.63.10 x.acme.com # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handle within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost

192.168.31.138 srva.flaman-m-quest-etna.nx
192.168.31.128 srvb.quest-etna.nx
192.168.31.128 drupal.flaman-m-quest-etna.nx
192.168.31.139 datas.flaman-m-quest-etna.nx
```

Do you know if something is wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, this is not the best way but I disabled my firewalld in CentOS and it works.

```
sudo service disable firewalld
sudo service stop firewalld
```

You can just configure it too to make it works.